# At what point in session set up is DNS “called”

Tags: dns, ip-address, tcp

I’m not asking about how DNS does its “thing” of converting domain names to IP addresses – I can find a wealth of very good information on that. What I can’t seem to find a description of is how and when an application interacts with DNS to establish a connection between two parties. My misunderstanding will become clear in the way I write this question - that isn't deliberate, I just can't get my head around this "DNS interaction".

If there is a web link (that I haven’t found) that explains the answer to my question please just provide that.

Let me give a simple scenario. I want to access my favourite website, fruity-pies.

So I type into my web browser: http://www.fruity-pies.com

Now, early on in the “connection process” that address needs to be converted into an IP address – that’s what DNS does for me. DNS, or maybe more accurately BIND(?), “works” at the application layer as does HTTP. So I am thinking that somehow HTTP (or whatever service I am using such as ftp) “knows” a call to DNS/BIND (?) is required. What is sent is the domain name, fruity-pies.com, what comes back is the IP address of the resource, 213.1.19.34 ?. Is this what happens? IF this is correct then every application layer process would have to have the code to "call" DNS and that duplication just doesn't seem correct to me.

Although the application has received the IP address from DNS, this only becomes important at the network layer. So is the IP address passed from the application layer to the transport layer, but ignored, because it isn’t relevant at the transport layer? The transport layer splits the original message into packets and adds the port number to identify which process handles the message at the destination. Then the data packet gets passed with the IP address (that came from the application layer interaction with DNS/BIND) to the network layer that puts the IP address on as a header? Is that correct?

Sorry if that is a misunderstanding, but to emphasise my main issue at the moment is how DNS/BIND fits into the setup of the communication. I can see that once the IP address has been resolved DNS/BIND is no further needed for this particular communication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have worked out the solution to my question for an IPv4 connection. Original Python source from https://wiki.python.org/moin/TcpCommunication

I believe when an application tries to communicate with some "remote" process using **sockets**, whether or not the service of DNS is required happens as a result of the parameters passed to the application socket. So in the following extract from a client coded in Python 3 that is attempting to connect to a remote location

```
import socket
```

<< This tells Python the program will want to make a network connection, so include the necessary code

```
TCP_IP = 'www.fruity-pies.com'
```

<< This is where the app wants to connect to

```
TCP_PORT = 40375
```

<< This is the port the client app  wants to connect to at fruity-pies

```
BUFFER_SIZE = .....
MESSAGE = .......

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
```

<< This creates(?) a socket and indicates I want to use IPv4 (AF_INET) and TCP (SOCK_STREAM) protocols to communicate

```
s.connect((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))
```

<< This is the attempt to connect to the remote location. Since the remote address is a string, 'www.fruity-pies.com' , this gets intercepted and name resolution, either via a local host file or the DNS, tries to find a record to translate www.fruity-pies.com into an IP address.

```
.... rest of code
```

I think my misunderstanding was based on an idea that TCP/IP processing worked in the same way as OSI layers and that each "call" passed parameters "down" to the next layer. So if an OSI application runs at level 7 then some Level 6 process receives the connection request. Similarly I thought that making a socket call from an application attempting to communicate with a remote process, where the target address was expressed as a string, say www.fruity-pies.com, that some Transport Layer process would be responsible for translating this to an IP address. This isn't the way it seems to work.